# Passing the variable from one class to another

Tags: java, class, variables

Hello everyone I'm currently creating a simple program. I have 2 classes the first one is SampleReturn and the second one is GetValues. What I want to happen is that when I enter a name in GetValues class the name I entered will be stored in a variable and later on will be used by the SampleReturn class to display the name. Unfortunately, I can't run the program because it has an error. The code is below please help me with regards to this matter. I'm just self studying I really want to learn Java. Thanks! :)

Code in GetValues Class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class GetValues{
    Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void wew(){
        System.out.println("Enter name: ");
        String a = inp.nextLine();

        private static String z = a;

        public static String kuhaName(){
            return z;
        }
    }
}
```

Code in SampleReturn:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class SampleReturn{
        public static void main(String[]args){

        String nameMo = GetValues.kuhaName();

        System.out.print("Your name is: " +nameMo);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check your code. You have not closed the `wew()` method body with curly brace `}`

Comment: it says illegal start of expression in the line private static String z = a;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your Code should be something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GetValues
{
    private static Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static String z = "";
    public static void wew()
    {
        System.out.println("Enter name: ");
        String a = inp.nextLine();
        z = a;
    }
    public static String kuhaName()
    {
        return z;
    }
}
```

And then `SampleRun.java` should be like this:

```
//import java.util.Scanner;//no need to import
public class SampleReturn
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        GetValues.wew();//First input the name .
        String nameMo = GetValues.kuhaName();//Retrieve the name
        System.out.print("Your name is: " +nameMo);//Display the name
    }
}
```

Comment: there is an error in line private static String z = a; it says cannot find symbol variable a

Comment: My mistake....missed that line. `a` is local variable in method `wew()` so value of `a` could not be assigned to `z` outside the method. See my update.

Comment: there is another error sir in the line String a = inp.nextLine(); it says non static variable inp cannot be referenced from a static context

Comment: Scanner object `inp` should be declared as static as `non-static` variables could not be called from static method ..

Answer (score 3):

You have a few problems going on in this code.

First of all, you can't have a method within another method. Second of all, you're never calling `wew` which will actually read the input. Assuming you meant something like this:

```
public class GetValues{
    Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static String z;

    public static void wew(){
        System.out.println("Enter name: ");
        String a = inp.nextLine();

        z = a;
    }

    public static String kuhaName(){
        return z;
    }
}
```

All you have to do now is call your methods in order.

Answer (score 2):

Well the first thing that comes to mind is that the `wew` method doesn't have an ending brace `}`

you also can't declare a field inside of your method.  you probably want to declare `private static String z` outside of the `wew` method.

---

I've read your assignment, and althought I'm not going to entirely do your homework for you, I can give you advice on the architecture of your program.

First I'd make a class called `Person`.  You can call your class whatever you want, but for the rest of this post, I'll refer to this class as the `Person` class.

now you'll want your class to have:

- a field to store the `name` of your `Person`
- a method to get input from the user, and to put that into the `name` field.
- a method to print the content of the `name` field.

in your `main` method you'll want to

- instantiate your `Person`
- call it's input-getting method
- call it's printing method.

Comment: how would I do that? I'm completely a newbie sir would you please give me the answer?

Comment: @AngelCasiMontoya well, what is your actual requirement?  what is your program actually supposed to do?

Comment: Like what I said awhile ago, When the user input a name in GetValues class, that name will then be stored inside a variable and will be used by the class SampleReturn to display the name

Comment: @AngelCasiMontoya that's implementation details. You don't even need an extra class to read input from the command line.  What is your real requirement?

Comment: What requirement? can you please specify sir?

Comment: @AngelCasiMontoya why are you writing this program

Comment: It's because our professor told us to do a program that will use a variable from one method/ class to another method/ class. Which in my case, I used 2 classes instead of putting it in 2 methods.

Comment: @AngelCasiMontoya do you have a written definition of your assignment?

Comment: Write a program that has 2 classes or 2 methods which will require the user to input a name in the first class or first method and then will display the name in the second class or second method.

Comment: @AngelCasiMontoya I've edited my post to give you more details