# How to get data from a jTextField or jFormattedTextField in another java class

Tags: java, swing, class, jtextfield, jformattedtextfield

I'm trying to use to different classes on netbeans, one is my GUI (also, i'm starting at programming and just learned what is one GUI), and in this one, I have some jTextField's and JFormattedTextField's, the other one, I want to use as back-end, for starters, I want to delete a information that I already have on my DB.

The error I get is this:

> error: cannot find symbol
> if(jFormattedTextFieldCPF.getText().equals("")){
> symbol:   variable jFormattedTextFieldCPF
> location: class Modos

Here's the first part of my code:

```
private void jButtonExcluirActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                               

    
    MODO = 1;// it sends which action the button have to do
    funcao.funcoes(MODO);
    
    

    // TODO add your handling code here:

}
```

In the class Modos I only have a function called funcoes, where there will be more actions to do on my DB, like, edit, add, search...

```
public void funcoes(int MODO) {
    
    if (MODO == 1){
        
                PreparedStatement stm;
    try {
        /*jFormattedTextFieldCPF.setEnabled(true);
        jTextFieldNOME.setEnabled(false);
        jTextFieldIDADE.setEnabled(false);
        jFormattedTextFieldDATA.setEnabled(false);
        jTextFieldAPELIDO.setEnabled(false);
                    */
        stm = conecta.conn.prepareStatement("delete from cad_pessoa where cad_cpf=?");
        
        
        if(jFormattedTextFieldCPF.getText().equals("")){
            
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Por favor completar o campo CPF");
            conecta.conn.rollback();
        }
        
        else {
            
        
        stm.setString(1, jFormattedTextFieldCPF.getText()); //pega o nome que será deletado
        stm.execute(); //executa o SQL
        conecta.conn.commit();
        
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Excluído!");
        
        /*jFormattedTextFieldCPF.setText("");
        jTextFieldNOME.setText(""); //deixa o campo vazio
        jTextFieldIDADE.setText("");
        jFormattedTextFieldDATA.setText("");//deixa o campo vazio
        jTextFieldAPELIDO.setText(""); //deixa o campo vazio
        
        jFormattedTextFieldCPF.setEnabled(false); //deixa o campo indisponivel
        jTextFieldNOME.setEnabled(false);
        jTextFieldIDADE.setEnabled(false);
        jFormattedTextFieldDATA.setEnabled(false);
        jTextFieldAPELIDO.setEnabled(false);
        jButtonINSERIR.setEnabled(true);
        jButtonALTERAR.setEnabled(false);*/
        
        // as a comentary cuz everything is a jFrame and gives an error
        }

    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Pessoa.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Erro:01\n" + ex.getMessage());
        
    }
        
    }
```

Sorry for the long question, To simplify, I want to get the info on the jFormattedTextField in another class.

Comment: The error is pretty obvious, `jFormattedTextFieldCPF` is undefined in the class `Modos`.  The problem is pretty basic Java 101.  You need to pass the information required by your class/method from your other class

Comment: Ok, and how to do it?  I also need to do the same thing in all the swing elements

Comment: Change `funcoes` to accept the input it needs to execute

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a static variable of type jTextField, inside your method initialize this static variable with the same object jFormattedTextField after modifications, declare a static get method to get this variable from another class and call it.

```
 class WhereYourJTextExists{
  private  jTextField jText ;
  private static jTextField jToPass;

  public static  jTextField getJToPass(){
   return jToPass;
  }
  public void yourTaskHere(){
  // .... do some tasks with jText
  // initialize your variable with the jTextField 
  jToPass= jText;
  }
  }
  // ----------------------------------
  class OtherClass{
  public void needJtextHere(){
  jTextField recievedJtext = WhereYourJTextExists.getJToPass();
  //...do your job with the recived jTextField 
  }
  }
```

Comment: Doesn't work

The mistake is said to be here:

` public void funcoes jFormattedTextFieldCPF (int MODO) {
        
        jTextField recievedjFormattedTextFieldCPF = Pessoa.getjToPass();`

error: '(' expected
    public void funcoes jFormattedTextFieldCPF (int MODO) {

Comment: public void funcoes jFormattedTextFieldCPF <=== you have a blanc character between funcoes and jFormattedTextFieldCPF  , delete it , also you can see this answer to see how to pass variables from a class to another :  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15029480/passing-the-variable-from-one-class-to-another

Answer (score 0):

Decouple your code.  Pass all the information that `funcoes` needs in order to do it's job and have it throw one or more exceptions as needed, for example...

```
public void funcoes(int MODO, String cpf) throws SQLException {

    if (MODO == 1) {
        if (cpf.equals("")) {
            // This could be a custom exception, which would make it easier 
            // to detect and display a custom error message
            throw new SQLException("Por favor completar o campo CPF");
        } else {
            try (PreparedStatement stm = conecta.conn.prepareStatement("delete from cad_pessoa where cad_cpf=?")) {
                stm.setString(1, jFormattedTextFieldCPF.getText()); //pega o nome que será deletado
                stm.execute(); //executa o SQL
                conecta.conn.commit();
            }
        }
    }
}
```